# Postgres copy data between tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've created `table1` with columns `a,b,c,d` which has data in it. 
`table2` is basically the same as `table1` it has different columns order + additional column i.e. `a,e,d,b,c` with no data.

how can I copy the data from `table1` into `table2` note that column `a` is an `id` and i wish the number will stay the same.

this is what I've already tried:

```
insert into table2 select (a,d,b,c) from table1
```

this resulted in `column "a" is of type bigint but expression is of type record`

```
insert into table2 (a,d,b,c) values(select a,d,b,c from table1)
```

didn't work either `syntax error at or near "select"`

```
insert into table2 (a,e,d,b,c) values(select a,NULL,d,b,c from table1)
```

got the error: `INSERT has more target columns than expressions`

Comment: [... the fine manual on `INSERT.`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-insert.html)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Specify the column names you are inserting, but do not use `values` when defining the select.

```
insert into table2(a,d,b,c) select a, d, b, c  from table1
```

Comment: Is this a good solution from performance perspective in case of >1mln rows?

Answer (score 2):

You can copy data between tables in postgreSQL by using:

`INSERT INTO [Tablename]([columns]) SELECT [Columns] FROM [Table to copy form];`

Which in your case would look like:

`INSERT INTO table2(a,b,c,d) SELECT a,b,c,d FROM table1;`

You can also easily create an empty table with the same table structure so that copying to it is easy, by using the command:

`CREATE TABLE [New Table] AS [Old Table] WITH NO DATA;`

And then running the `INSERT` command from before.

If you simply want an identical copy you can run:
`CREATE TABLE [New Table] as [Old Table];`

You can read more about copying data between tables in this article which I wrote for dataschool:
https://dataschool.com/learn/copying-data-between-tables

You can read more about the insert command in the documentation here:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/sql-insert.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the first solution is actually the parentheses. If you do:

```sql
insert into table2 select a,d,b,c from table1
```

it's going to work, given `table2` has the same number of columns in the right order.

This happens because in Postgres if you do

```sql
select (1, 2), 3
```

it means you are selecting one field of type record and values 1 and 2 inside of it and one field of type int with value 3.